# Webpart visible in edit but disappears in preview

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

**UPDATE**
I've tested on different tenants, it seems to only work in those that isn't a first release tenant.

It doesn't even work with the default built-in webparts that have been served by microsoft.

Could someone please check this as-well?

-Ole

Suddenly my projects are not working at all in preview mode when in the tenant context. It renders absolutley ok in edit, but as soon as I hit "Preview", everything disappears from the screen. In Chrome, I can see the components in the react console and data is changing?

No code change.
This started yesterday.

I also created the default helloworld to see if that worked, but sadly no.

Anybody experienced this?

[10:18:43] Project test version: 0.0.1

[10:18:43] Build tools version: 3.2.7

[10:18:43] Node version: v6.11.2

[10:18:43] Total duration: 6.2 s

[image: Blank preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were in contact with MS support, but we didn't get a proper answer. They had done a change that should fix it, but we used our own work around in stead. What we did was turning off the first release setting and then we were able to use the workbench properly. It isn't the answer, but it's a work around.

Ole

Answer (score 0):

do one thing in the main div which is returned add style : visibility:"visible"